# Does using a DataTemplate in the View create a coupling between View and ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I just started looking into WPF and MVVM-Light a couple of days ago. At first I created a single windows desktop app and now I want to create a desktop app with several pages.
I read [this tutorial](http://codelinq.wordpress.com/category/wpf-mvvm-light/) and I think I understand the concept.

But I have one question. MVVM-Light uses the `ViewModelLocator` to avoid having a strong link between the view and the viewmodel. But does using a `DataTemplate` in the MainWindow.xaml (to associate view and viewModel) not go against this principle?  Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I tried to help out by improving your question's readability a bit and adding some tags.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people use the DataTemplate method,that's fine.  The other widely used method, setting DataContext to your ViewModel in code-behind, also creates a "link" between them.  If there is no link, nothing would ever work at all.

Comment: I find this post : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/120090/who-should-control-navigation-in-an-mvvm-application.

SonOfPirate seems to have another solution, using convention in the viewModel name and view name. But I'm too beginner to fully understand his explanation

Comment: Well I understand that you can use dataTemplate in the view without go against MVVM but if someone can provide me a simple example of what SonOfPirate explains in this message, it would be perfect ;)